# iOS upload/download data to/from azure blob with background process

Tags: ios, azure

I'm building an app in which one component is uploading/downloading data from an azure blob. I have been looking for ways to make this run in the background so that the processes aren't interrupted when the app is minimised or the phone is put to sleep. I don't need to support these processes when the app is killed. Is there a way to do this?

https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-ios/issues/81 was the only relevant thing I could find, and it doesn't offer much.

Does anyone know how this can be done?